# How to show Progress bar while loading page in div using Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, jquery

I am loading another page in one div using jQuery.Load("#divid","pageURL");

I have anchor tag on that anchor tag click I am calling jQuery.load("#divid","pageURL"); function this function takes time to load page in that div, so I want to show loading image and changing the cursor style.

Below is the code snippet which I am using currently.
in script.js file I have written function like that

```
function loadReview(el) {

    jQuery("#productName1").load(el);

    return false;
}
```

and I have anchor tag inside .aspx page like that.

```
<a onclick='loadReview(\"" + strexternalURL + "\");' href='#productName1'></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use success method

```
function loadReview(el) {
    $("div.loaderDiv").html('<img src="imglink" />');
    $("div.loaderDiv").show();

    $("#productName1").load(el);

    return false;

    success: $("div.loaderDiv").hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery( "#productName1" ).load(el, function() {
   //loaded
   jQuery("#productName1").addClass("loaded");
});
```

with in your css something like this:

```
#productName1 {
   background-image: url('images/loading.gif');
   background-position: center center;
}

#productName1.loaded {
   background-image: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add a script to simulate loading before the call and when the call is finished, remove.

example:

```
function loadReview(el) {
    // add a gif loading in a div loader
    jQuery("div.loadingDiv").html('<img src="link gif loading" />');
    jQuery("div.loadingDiv").show();
    jQuery("#productName1").load(el, function() {
        jQuery("div.loadingDiv").hide();
    });

    return false;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="loadingDiv" style="display:none"></div>
<a onclick='loadReview(\"" + strexternalURL + "\");' href='#productName1'></a>
```