# display procentage indicator while page is loading (ajax)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I was searching for solution all night yesterday and i couldnt find working example, i made some initial progress though. In console log i can see that code has been loaded partialy so i got some % stages of loading.

When i hit refresh this is what i get in console log:

```
6.826666666666667% 
13.653333333333334% 
20.48% 
27.30666666666667% 
34.13333333333333% 
40.96% 
47.78666666666667% 
54.61333333333334% 
61.44% 
68.26666666666666% 
75.09333333333333% 
81.92% 
88.74666666666667% 
95.57333333333334% 
100%
```

The problem im having is that it isnt shown in real time, "on fly" sort of. Both progress bar and console log are displayed AFTER page is loaded not while it is loading. So progress bar is just at 0 % at start and when page is loaded it goes straight to 100%.

This is where i started: http://www.dave-bond.com/blog/2010/01/JQuery-ajax-progress-HMTL5/

This is actual code im using:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({
  xhr: function()
  {
   var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
      if (evt.lengthComputable) {
          $("#progress-bar").css('width', '' + (100 * evt.loaded / evt.total) + '%');
        var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total * 100 + '%';
        //Do something with download progress
        console.log(percentComplete);

      }
    }, false);
    return xhr;

  },
  type: 'POST',
  url: "prog-dat.php",
  data: ({status: 264}),
  success: function(data){
    jQuery("#content").html(data);
    jQuery("#content").show();
  }
});
</script>

<div id="progress-bar"></div>
<div id="content" style="display:none;"></div>
```

Process file atm is this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['status'])) {

for($a=0;$a<10;$a++){ 
     for($b=0;$b<10;$b++){ 
           for($c=0;$c<10;$c++){ 
               for($d=0;$d<10;$d++){ 
                 echo $a.$b.$c.$d.", "; 
               } 
            } 
       } 
 } 
}
?>
```

Ive tried to put large pictures instead of php code it doesnt change anything i also tried include older jquery library 1.4.4 and i used older method introduced in the link i posted above (before send method) it also works the same way - it doesnt show progress while it is loading i can only examin stages in console, cos it gives data back after page is loaded.

Is there anyone who could explain and give example of how it works in real time?

Comment: Have you considered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19808851/how-to-show-progress-bar-while-loading-page-in-div-using-jquery ?

Comment: i dont want just show some gif i want % of current page load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had an equally torrid time trying to get a progress bar to work. Here's what I did (using JQuery UI's progress bar styling):

```
    $.ajaxSetup({
        async: true,
        xhr: function() {
            var TimeOut=null;
            var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
            //Download progress
            xhr.addEventListener('progress', function(evt) {
                if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                    var percentComplete = (evt.loaded / evt.total) * 100;
                    if (percentComplete==100) {
                        $('#progress').css('width', '100%');
                        TimeOut=setTimeout(function() { $('#loadingoverlay').remove() }, 1000);
                    } else {
                        TimeOut=null;
                        if ($('#loadingoverlay').length==0) {
                            $('body').append('<div style="margin: auto; top: 0px; left: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; padding: 0px; position: fixed; height: auto; z-index: 10000; background-color: rgba(125, 125, 125, 0.8);" id="loadingoverlay"><div id="loader" class="ui-corner-all" style="margin: auto; width: 25%; position: relative; top: 50%;"><div aria-valuenow="20" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuemin="0" role="progressbar" class="ui-progressbar ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" id="progressbar"><div id="progress" style="width: '+percentComplete+'%;" class="ui-progressbar-value ui-widget-header ui-corner-left"></div></div></div></div>');
                        } else {
                            $('#progress').css('width', percentComplete+'%');
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, false);
            return xhr;
        }
    });
```

Comment: can you show some html code of the file beacuse i implemented it and it still doesnt work, i mean doesnt show in real time, maybe i did something wrong, if i could see other code that is related to that script i could make it to work